# Can't get Java JPA example running?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, transactions, wildfly

(old message):
I am trying to get my Java JPA WAR-Project running acording to the [JPA Reference Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JPA+Reference+Guide). I am using Wildfly 8 and a MySQL database. But I get errors as soon as I try to persist with the EntityManager. I'm really stuck here! :( Does anybody know what's wrong??

(edit):
Ok, my current status is this one below. I cannot delete @ManagedBean, because I need to make the call from the XHTML page (RichFaces). Therefore, I put all the JPA-stuff in a separate class DbAccess. The program runs, but as soon as I press the button to make the call to Index.doContentMock() which then links to DbAccess.doContentMock(), I get the error posted below.
Whats wrong?

(edit 2):
For some reason the EntityManager still does not work after the changments with injecting DbAccess.
Why doesn't the EntityManager work?

My XHTML caller class:

```
import com.glasses.abc.business.Content;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@ManagedBean
public class Index {

    @Inject
    DbAccess dba;

    public void doContentMock() {
        System.out.println("XXXXX AUFRUFEN VON Index.doContentMock()");
        dba.doContentMock();
    }
}
```

My Content entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Content implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String contentCode;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getContentCode() {
        return this.contentCode;
    }

    public void setContentCode(String contentCode) {
        this.contentCode = contentCode;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Content)) {
            return false;
        }
        Content other = (Content) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.glasses.abc.business.Content[ id=" + id + ", contentCode='" + contentCode + "' ]";
    }

}
```

My new DbAccess class:

```
@Stateful
public class DbAccess {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "AbcPU", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED) // default type is PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION
    EntityManager em;

    public void doContentMock() {
        System.out.println("XXXXX 0");
        System.out.println(em);
        System.out.println("XXXXX 1");
        Content content = new Content();
        System.out.println("XXXXX 2");
        content.setId((long) 5);
        System.out.println("XXXXX 3");
        content.setContentCode("Hier ist ein bestimmter Code, der in die Datenbank soll!");
        System.out.println("XXXXX 4");
        System.out.println(content);
        try {
        em.persist(content);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("XXXXX Could not persist:");
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("XXXXX 5");
    }
}
```

My persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="AbcPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pwd"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My Error:

```
22:58:17,695 INFO  [stdout] (default task-10) XXXXX 0
22:58:17,695 INFO  [stdout] (default task-10) ExtendedEntityManager [abc.war#AbcPU]
22:58:17,695 INFO  [stdout] (default task-10) XXXXX 1
22:58:17,696 INFO  [stdout] (default task-10) XXXXX 2
22:58:17,696 INFO  [stdout] (default task-10) XXXXX 3
22:58:17,696 INFO  [stdout] (default task-10) XXXXX 4
22:58:17,696 INFO  [stdout] (default task-10) com.glasses.abc.business.Content[ id=5, contentCode='Hier ist ein bestimmter Code, der in die Datenbank soll!' ]
22:58:17,697 INFO  [stdout] (default task-10) XXXXX Could not persist:
22:58:17,697 INFO  [stdout] (default task-10) org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.glasses.abc.business.Content
22:58:17,698 INFO  [stdout] (default task-10) XXXXX 5
22:58:17,702 INFO  [stdout] (default task-10) XXXXX AUFRUFEN VON getContent(0)
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You aren't creating a transaction.

Comment: How would I have to create one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the persistence context annotation add another attribute like this:
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "AbcPU", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)

Then it may work.

Comment: Still does not work. If I do that I get another error. I will post it as an answer below. Any idea?

Comment: remove managedbean annotation but keep the @PersistencContext annotation as specified in my answer

Comment: I can't remove the @ManagedBean, because if I do I will not be able to make the call from the index.xhtml. I will update my status using "edit" on my first post. (Sorry, didn't know that was done that way here in Stack...)

Comment: Ok, edited the post to the current status. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: now the bean is not getting instantiated,thats why nullpointerexception

Comment: How would I have to instantiate it?

Comment: Add @RequestScoped above the Index class

Comment: Did it, but the EntityManager remains null! There are actually 2 types of @RequestScoped:

-> javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped

-> javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped

I tried both and both return null.

Comment: Why is the EntityManager null? I thought it was injected...?

Comment: Because you have to use @Inject annotation in Index class for ejb "DbAccess" to be injected.then entity manager will also be injected.you should not use DbAccess dba = new DbAccess();

Comment: So what I have to do is take all the stuff in DbAccess and put it back into Index? Though if I do that I will have to delete '@ManagedBean from Index. And if I do that I will not be able to access Index from the XHTML. Therefore, Index will never be started. How does that make sense? What's wron with DbAccess? What doesn't injection work in DbAccess?

Comment: I just mean keep the DbAccess at the same place where it is now.But in your index class get the DBAcess injected then entitymanager will be injected.Now since your are creating DbAccess then entitymanager does not get created which result in nullpointerexception

Comment: Ok, I changed to code by keeping DbAccess, but injecting it in Index. But the EntityManager still does not work. I altered the uppoer posting with my code. Why doesn't the EntityManager persist? Is say that the EntityManager is detached...?

Comment: check whether that Id is already present.If yes then change it

Comment: That's the point. The program never created any table called "content" in the database "abc". Therefore, the id cannot exist. I posted the Content entity class above in the main post. Why isn't the table "content" created?

Comment: Is the Content an Entity class?

Comment: Yes, the Content is an entity class marked with @Entity and meant to be a table called entity in the database abc. I posted the class above. Why doesn't it work?